# Combining html and ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

I have HTML code in my Rails application that looks like this:

```
<td><%= MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name %></td>
```

And this shows up fine. However, the field `some_id` is not always present in the database, so I'd like to display `NA` rather than `MyObj`'s name in those cases.

So here's what I mean in pseudocode:

```
<td><%= IF @my_obj.some_id is NIL THEN "NA" ELSE MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name %></td>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Um, your pseudocode has a pretty direct translation into Ruby and the stuff inside `<%= ... %>` is just Ruby code so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
<td><%= @my_obj.some_id.present? ? MyObj.find(@my_obj.some_id).name : 'NA' %></td>
```

However, you're exposing yourself to some pretty big issues if you're finding records in your view code like this.  Your controller should handle that kind of logic.

Comment: great, thanks. I didn't know you could do that sort of thing in ruby

Comment: @CodeGuy Just heed the warning -- just because you can do something like this in ruby, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be hitting the database in your view code, leave that to your controllers. Try loading the object in your controller instead:

```
# use this code to your controller
@view_obj = MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id)
```

You can then use the [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method to set the name, which will return `nil` instead of raising the usual `NoMethodError` if the object is `nil`:

```
<%= @view_obj.try(:name) || "NA" %>
```

Answer (score -2):

<%= !MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name.blank? ? MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name : "NA" %>

Comment: This will raise a `NoMethodError` exception if `MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id)` returns `nil`, which is precisely the situation the question is about.

Comment: <%= MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id)!=nil && !MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name.blank? ? MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).name : "NA" %>

Comment: If you want to do it that way, it should just be `<%= MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj.some_id).nil? ? "NA" : MyObj.find_by_id(@my_obj_some_id).name %>` -- from the question there's no need to check if the name is blank or not, just if the object exists. You're also hitting the database multiple times in that one line which isn't a good idea (sure it'll probably be cached, but still), especially in a view.

Comment: you are right. i am replying according to questioner's code so. it should be stored somewhere in an instance.

Comment: Going to the database for the initial check is aggressive if you already have the original object loaded.  You can check the id first, and assuming foreign keys are linked correctly, you can rely on the name attribute being accessible and not triggering a no method error.  If this is a large application, unnecessarily going to the database in the view is very bad practice and should be avoided.